# Sum of hours (HH:MM) in Linq

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.0

I am having "TimeClocked" in my database table in the format HH.mm and I want to sum all the "TimeClocked" using LINQ.

I have tried this aggregate function.

```
var data = _projectDbContext
    .Tasks
    .Where(x => x.Project.CompanyId == companyId && x.Status == true)
    .Select(e => TimeSpan.Parse(e.TimeClocked))
    .Aggregate(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0), (total, next) => total + next)
    .ToString();
```

I am using **EF Core 3.0.0**. It's showing error like this.

```
Processing of the LINQ expression 'Aggregate<TimeSpan, TimeSpan>(
    source: Select<TaskEntity, TimeSpan>(
        source: Where<TaskEntity>(
            source: DbSet<TaskEntity>, 
            predicate: (x) => x.Project.CompanyId == (Unhandled parameter: __companyId_0) && x.Status == True), 
        selector: (e) => Parse(e.TimeClocked)), 
    seed: (Unhandled parameter: __p_1), 
    func: (total, next) => total + next)' by 'NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor' failed. This may indicate either a bug or a limitation in EF Core. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101433 for more detailed information.
```

Any help will be grateful.

Comment: Yeh, I am storing my TimeClocked(HH: mm) field as a string in my db. Before I using EF Core 3 the aggregate functions were working perfectly for me.I think this issue due to EF Core 3 completely blocking the client side execution of Linq queries.

Answer (score 5):

It happens due to [restricted client evalution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/#restricted-client-evaluation) in `EF Core 3` so you have to call `AsEnumerable` right before untranslatable expressions

```
var data = _projectDbContext
    .Tasks
    .Where(x => x.Project.CompanyId == companyId && x.Status == true)
    .AsEnumerable() // switches to LINQ to Objects
    .Select(e => TimeSpan.Parse(e.TimeClocked))
    .Aggregate(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0), (total, next) => total + next)
    .ToString();
```

Comment: It's working fine But when we are using AsEnumerable() it'll work in client-side(due to restricted client evalution in EF Core 3).Could you please help me to write Linq query for completely convert to native SQl query.

Comment: @AjasAju I'm afraid it's not possible to use `Aggregate` in `EF`. My initial idea was using `Sum` but this is not possible to use it with `TimeSpan`. Probably you can use stored functions for this but i'm not sure

Comment: @AjasAju What is the actual data type in the database? Is `TimeClocked` stored as a string? Is it possible to change it?

Comment: Yup, The actual data stored as a string. I don't think it can be change the datatype due to some reasons.